# Actuarial Question on finding frequency distribution of unknown distribution after change in deductible

Tags: probability

Losses have a Pareto distribution with α=2 and mean 900. Initially there is an ordinary deductible of 720 per loss and no policy limit, and the frequency distribution for the number of payments has probability function $\Pr(N_d=k)=0.43−0.12k$, $k=0,1,2,3$. The deductible is then reduced but a policy limit of 8,400 is introduced so that the expected cost per loss remains the same as that before the change.

How do I find the new frequency distribution for number of payments after the reduction in deductibles? As in how do I find $\Pr(N_d*=k)$ for $k=0,1,2,3$, where d* is the new deductible?

Note: I have learnt how to change the parameter for (a,b,0) and (a,b,1) distribution but in this case, pareto is not included in such groups of distribution. And the frequency distribution is an unknown one.

Comment: Try this forum for SOA/CAS exam questions http://www.actuarialoutpost.com/actuarial_discussion_forum/index.php